# omniauth-genius strategy not working with omniauth 1.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Trying to use the omniauth-genius strategy with devise in rails 4 app keeps resulting in 'strategy not found' error.

If I add to devise.rb the following:

```
 config.omniauth :genius, ENV['GENIUS_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GENIUS_CLIENT_SECRET']
```

I get the following error: "Could not find a strategy with name `Genius'. Please ensure it is required or explicitly set it using the :strategy_class option. (Devise::OmniAuth::StrategyNotFound)"

Or, if I add to config/initializers/omniauth.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :genius, ENV['GENIUS_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GENIUS_CLIENT_SECRET']
end
```

I get the following error: "gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:50:in `rescue in provider': Could not find matching strategy for :genius. You may need to install an additional gem (such as omniauth-genius). (LoadError)"

Not sure why it can't find it since I have added both 'omniauth' and 'omniauth-genius' to my gemfile and have run bundle install.  Could this be related to omniauth-genius's dependency on omniauth 1.0?